# Mac App Store First Time Setup Pop Up?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mac-appstore

I Signed on Mac Store For First Time And Downloaded App.Pop-up came which says welcome to app store and it has new apple privacy icon with two man shaking hands and i clicked continue is that normal process or some adware ?

Answer (score 5):

That's a new Privacy process just introduced by Apple.  There's a new popup window that will display when you log into your iCloud account for the first time after the upgrade.

[image]
[image]

You can read more about it [here](http://www.alphr.com/apple/1008957/apple-icon-collecting-data).

> After installing the newly released iOS 11.3, macOS 10.13.4, and tvOS 11.3 software update, users will be met with a page that explains how a new icon, of two figures shaking hands, will appear “when an Apple feature asks to use your personal information”.
>
> The idea is that when personal information is being collected on iTunes, the App Store or other Apple services, users can tap through the icon to read more information about what sort of data is being asked for and how it is being used. It’s pitched by the company as a way for it to increase transparency around how it handles user data, aligned with GDPR rules.

Comment: pop which says welcome to mac app store is it normal ? and after that i have to click continue.

Comment: Yes, that's normal.  If you look at the article I linked to you'll see an explanation.

Comment: i know about privacy icon the pop up of welcome to app store that looks suspicious !

Comment: I updated the answer with the info that the popup, if it looks like that image, is normal.

Comment: The Pop Says Welcome To App Store And privacy icon was under it